# how to achieve @mention functionality where user not able to move cursor through spannable String like WhatsApp android App

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

e.g. 
**@Bob Turner** have a fun

above sample message is there in EditText. And User should not be able to move cursor through "@Bob Turner". When user tries to move cursor/ touch spannable string in EditText, it should move to either start or end of spannable string.

Comment: Have you solved it ??

Comment: ........not yet

Answer (score -1):

Here’s how to decide which one to use:

Just reading and not setting the text nor the spans? -> SpannedString

Setting the text and the spans? -> SpannableStringBuilder

Setting a small number of spans (<~10)? -> SpannableString

Setting a larger number of spans (>~10) -> SpannableStringBuilder

Refer following link

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/spantastic-text-styling-with-spans-17b0c16b4568